# Using the mkfs.ext 4 command with -c switch

Tags: installation, partitioning, hard-drive

I am currently using Ubuntu from a Live USB and in Gparted can see that my internal hdd has 1 partition /dev/sda1 size: 931.51 Gb, file system unknown.. I want to prepare this hard drive to install Ubuntu onto, but the disk utility tells me there are 798 bad sectors (which from doing a bit of research is approximately 0.00004%). Doing some reading in other forums, apparently running

```
mkfs.ext4 -c /dev/sda1
```

will create file system to which I can install Ubuntu and avoid the bad blocks in doing so. I really have no clue about this sort of thing, so just want to know if this will work or if it is the right way to go about it at least.

The reason I ask is because it is going to be a very time consuming process, as after 1h 35 mins it is only 0.08% done..

I am a complete linux n00b so please be as straightforward as possible in your responses, and thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Get rid of it, any hard drive with that many bad sectors will probably soon anyway.

Comment: 'with that many bad sectors'?! A quick google search tells me that a standard 1Tb HDD has close to 2 billion sectors, so your comment seems a bit invalid.